# How much memory does a Tomcat thread take?

Tags: tomcat, memory, threadpool

If I increase my Tomcat thread pool from N to N+1 threads, how much extra memory will that take?

Of course, my app might be responsible for some additional memory, but let's ignore that, I'm just interested in how much Tomcat takes.

I guess I could run a few tests and measure it myself, but I'm hoping that somebody has already done that and can share or point to the results.

Comment: Virtual memory? Physical memory?

Comment: Yes :-) Whatever information is available. Perhaps the more interesting question for Java is whether it's PermGenSpace vs. Heap etc.

Comment: Is your concern avoiding out of memory errors caused by insufficient virtual memory? Or is your concern performance problems caused by insufficient physical memory?

Answer (score 3):

The additional physical memory consumed will be effectively none at all. Until and unless the thread does work, the operating system won't waste physical memory holding its stack or related structures. (It will likely consume *some* physical memory, of course, because it will create the initial stack. But that can, and will, be paged out with no harm to performance if the thread isn't running.)

However, the thread's stack will consume virtual memory. You can tune the thread's maximum stack size, and it's the maximum stack size that controls how much virtual memory is consumed. If the thread just sits there, it's effectively free. It counts against virtual memory limits even though it consumes no real, limited resources.

If you encounter errors due to running out of virtual memory from thread stacks, probably your best option is to increase the virtual memory limit. The purpose of the virtual memory limit is to cap use of physical memory indirectly -- physical memory use won't exceed virtual memory use. But if you use programming patterns (like lots of threads) that consume virtual memory without corresponding use of physical memory, the limits just kick in when they shouldn't.

Of course, a 32-bit process is fundamentally limited to 2GB, 3GB, or 4GB of virtual memory (depending on the platform). So you may have no choice but to reduce the maximum thread stack size. (A thread immediately consumes virtual memory equal to its *maximum* stack size because the address space must be reserved even if it's never used.)

Reducing the maximum thread stack size is also an option. This is a compromise though. A larger *maximum* prevents the thread from causing an exception if it needs a lot of stack ever during its lifetime. And the only resource consumed is address space, which is ordinarily cheap. But the only practical limit you can impose on the program, to keep it from running low on physical memory and performing badly, is to limit virtual memory. So the knob you really want doesn't exist.

Comment: What if Tomcat has used the additional thread at least once to serve a request. Is it still "effectively free"? I wonder how much overhead there is.

Comment: It's effectively free, in terms of consumption of physical memory, when it's not actually in use because memory that hasn't been recently used is always eligible for paging. Page it out once and it never bothers you again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the primary memory usage will be the stack space allocated per thread. This is controllable on the command line via -Xss

Comment: That's the primary *virtual* memory usage.

Comment: Stack space is outside of the heap, but will still cause OutOfMemoryExceptions. Default can be as high as 1MB per thread (have to look up the default for your JVM)

Comment: Right, but 1MB of *physical* memory won't be used. So whether that matters depends on why he's asking.

Comment: I guess I fail to see your point. Everything is virtual memory, right up until the point it's swapped into physical. These stacks will absolutely take up physical memory when they are in use, otherwise they wouldn't be usable. If you have a 1MB stack size, 100 threads, and a server that is using those threads actively, you will have 100MB of physical memory in use. So, what is it that you are trying to say?

Comment: Would you know whether that is total memory or just what Java sees? I presume native threads also take some memory?

Comment: @rfeak They will take up physical memory *when they are in use*. If his threads use about 64KB of stack space, the *physical* memory usage will be about 64KB per thread, but the *virtual* memory usage will be 1MB per thread. Which number matters depends on why he's asking.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz -Not sure I buy that. My experience is that you can run out of memory simply by having the -Xss value set too high (or default) regardless of what your threads actually use in the stack under use. Real world example. I had a high thread count server that ran out of non-heap memory. Dialing back the -Xss setting to something smaller stopped the problem, yet didn't throw a StackOverflowException (had to do it :) ). If your theory was correct, I wouldn't have run out of memory in the first place. Modifying the setting would have no impact.

Comment: @rfeak You can run out of *virtual* memory, yes. (Think about it -- will more *physical* memory make a 'StackOverflowException' go away, of course not.) You can also run out of *physical* memory (your system will start swapping/paging, performance will suck). Since we don't know which issue the OP is concerned about, we don't know if "1MB" is right number.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I still don't see your point, and I don't think your comments are helping the OP, nor clarifying the answer. How about this. Offer a better answer for this gentleman. Cover both physical and virtual usage, seeing as you seem to think this is critical.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I have seen, **one new idle thread will take up about 20KB - 50KB of memory**.

From there, it can grow as it runs based on the stack depth (nested method calls) and the number of parameters and local variables (all primitives and pointers in method parameters and local variables get added to the stack. Whereas objects themselves are put on the heap).

The work-load (when the thread is working) will add to some memory usage, and then it can get cleared by the time the request gets completed. But, you can't attribute this to the new thread, because the work-load has to get picked by one thread or the other.

Long story short: *An additional thread is going to add about 0.05 MB of memory usage.*

Note 1: 
There seems to be a per-process limit to the number of threads. So, a linux implementation might allow a single JVM to create utmost 1000 or 2000 threads.

So, you have to ensure that all thread pools in your application add up to less than 2000 threads. Else the JVM might crash suddenly when that limit is breached.

Note 2:
JVM NMT wrongly reports Java 8 committed memory, automatically setting it to reserved memory. Refer: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8191369